# How to filter data in array object using mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a query that is running fine, now i have requirement to filter some data that is inside array. I don't know how to do that. Below is my code. Please guide me where i am wrong.

**Request data**

```
[
  'Online Casino/Betting',
  'Other ',
  'Prefer not to say ',
  'Do you really care ? :) ',
  'Spend time with friends'
]
```

**Database Data**

```
"interests" : [
        {
            "name" : "Computers/internet", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("60752406d8e7213e6b5306de"), 
            "id" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Astrology/Spiritualism", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("60752406d8e7213e6b5306df"), 
            "id" : NumberInt(3)
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Cars & motorbikes", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("60752406d8e7213e6b5306e0"), 
            "id" : NumberInt(2)
        }
    ],
```

**Query**

```
if (filterData.interests != undefined && filterData.interests.length > 0) {
  interests = {
    interests: { $elemMatch: { $and: [{ name: filterData.interests }] } }
  }
}

  User.aggregate([
      coordinatesCondition,
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            exerciseHabitsCondition,
            interests
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: lastActivity,
      },
      { $limit: skip + 12 },
      { $skip: skip },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "favorites",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "favorites.favoriteUserId",
          as: "favUsers",
        },
      },
    ])
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: To filter elements from an array in an aggregation use `$filter` array operator.

Comment: @prasad_ can you please elaborate. Actually i am passing data in array format.

Comment: I have array of names

Comment: @robin can you provide the exact mongoDB query being executed in the debug mode with minimal stages in aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my understanding you want to match the result with `interests` in the req data.
I am sharing a simple update, that can work well for you.

```js
if (filterData.interests != undefined && filterData.interests.length > 0) {
  interestsQuery = {
    'interests.name': { $in: filterData.interests } }
  }
}

User.aggregate([
      coordinatesCondition,
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            exerciseHabitsCondition,
            interestsQuery
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: lastActivity,
      },
    ])
```